# Recieving 'null' values from a jsp page into Struts2 Action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, null

I'm using Struts2+JSP as my J2EE platforms. Sometimes I get null values from struts text fields of my jsp page into actions. for example in the login page, despite of validating my forms and preventing of entering invalid data such as null or blank, I still get null value for the username field instead of the actual entered value.
has anyone come across such an occasion?

here is a piece of code in which this error happens:

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String username;
private String password;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation", "static-access" })
public String execute() {

    try {
        CacheLogger.getInstance().AddEnteredUsernameEvent(username);
        UserSession userSession = UserSession.getInstance();

        userSession.getPlayerById(username.toLowerCase()); //THE ONE WHERE I GET NULL VALUE (sometimes)
```

the respective JSP page:

```
<s:form action="login.action" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementsByName('password').item(0).value=sha1Hash(document.getElementsByName('password').item(0).value);return validateLogin()" style="text-align:center;">
<s:textfield name="username" maxlength="50" label="نام کاربری" tabindex="1" onfocus="hideMessage()" cssClass="loginTextField" />
<s:password  name="password" maxlength="255" label="رمز عبور" tabindex="2" onfocus="hideMessage()" cssClass="loginTextField"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ورود" class="submit" tabindex=3 onclick="javascript:$('#exception').css('display','none');$('#actionmessage').css('display','none');"/>
</s:form>
```

the piece of javaScript Validator:

```
function validateLogin()
{   
    var username = document.getElementsByName('username').item(0).value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName('password').item(0).value;
    var input=/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\d*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

    if(!username)
    {
        showErrorMessage('خطا! نام کاربری را وارد نکرده اید',26);
        return false;
    }
    else
    if(!password)
    {
        showErrorMessage('خطا! رمز عبور را وارد نکرده اید',25);
        return false;
    }
    else
    if(!input.test(username))
    {
        showErrorMessage('خطا! در قسمت "معین خر است" کاراکتر غیر مجاز وارد کرده اید',49);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does your action have a `getUsername()` method? Please show some code and the error message!

Comment: yes it does ->  
 public String getUsername() {
  return username;
 }
, I put the piece of code on the first post.

Comment: I edited the first post and added the JSP and JavaScript validator. I validate the Struts form in a javaScript function as you can see up there. even if a user disables JavaScript the sent data will be blank, not null.

Comment: @SJ.Jafari Have you got solution for this problem

Comment: @gnanz, actually, nope. this is happening sometimes! I just have to check the incoming values to be not null.

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple emements having name usename in your jsp page instead of using `document.getElementsByName` for getting text box value   try to get using form reference `document.formid.username.value`
  and also try setting empty value in your username textbox declaration like
 `<s:textfield  .... value="" />`

Comment: @SJ.Jafari Have you got solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

In the LoginAction class, you will need to have the getter and setter method for the attributes you want to receive from the jsp page. Try to add the getter and setters to it.

Comment: Actually there are getters and setters in there. without them struts doesn't work! as I mentioned before, this problem occurs occasionally.